# Is there any way to give an image round borders using CSS?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have an image which is square 100px by 100px.

Was wondering if there was any way for giving an image rounded borders using CSS?

Similar to the border-radius property:

```
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
```

I would prefer not to resort to Javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: This should work fine in modern browsers (no IE, basically). Try it within an `img { ... }` block.

Comment: @Kevin border-radius works in IE9 FYI

Comment: I don't like to call IE a browser :P . Yeah it would be nice to style the img without using a background image in the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-moz-border-radius: 15px;` and `-webkit-border-radius:15px;` should work fine in a standards compliant browser.  Another technique:

```
<div style="border: 0px solid; border-radius: 30px; -moz-border-radius: 30px; -khtm border-radius: 30px; -webkit-border-radius: 30px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: url('img.jpg');">
```

Comment: Oh so I can apply the styles straight to the image class? Cool will give it a try.

Comment: @Ryan Applying border-radius on image elements doesn't seem to work in Opera - [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/gYaZh/)

Comment: @Šime Vidas Oh ok that's interesting. I still think the applying the border-radius property to the image element will be the nicest way. I think hardly anyone uses Opera to view our current website.